# uninstall does not call the custom action always

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-installer, custom-action

I have made a setup of a web application which could be installed multiple times in the same machine. I need to remove the sites created during installation at the time of uninstallation process. For this I wrote a custom action using a installer class.

Now, the problem is, if I have multiple installation of the same web application, custom uninstallation is being called only during the uninstallation of the last application.

Can somebody please help?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What tool did you use to author the MSI?  What conditional expression did you use for the custom action?

My guess is you used a tool that abstracted you from this and that you are using component action states.  It's not until the last client ( product ) of the shared component uninstalls that the component uninstalls and therefore the custom action is executed.

You should also know that installer class custom actions are known for their fragility.  Using a WiX DTF ( Windows Installer XML, Deployment Tools Foundation ) managed custom action would be a much wiser choice.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2010 and windows setup project. I have not mentioned any condition in the custom action. I have one more project apart from Setup which contains the Installer class. Inside the instaler class I have overridden method like Install, Commit, and Uninstall. The custom actions mentioned in Install and Commit are invoked every time I try to install the application. But when I try to uninstall the application, the custom action is not called for Uninstall.  It is only called if there is only one product installed.

Comment: All windows installer custom actions, even "uninstall" custom actions in Visual Studio, have a condition.  Visual Studio just hides this from you.  One of the many reasons Microsoft killed the project type in VS2012.   Take a look at the built MSI using ORCA and you'll see that my analysis is correct.